Android Compose state not available inside kotlin Coroutines
I have something like this :
class MyViewmodel(repository: Repository, sv: SaveStateHandle): Viewmodel() {

        var user by mutableStateOf(User(id = "", name = "") 
        private set
 init {

     user = User(id = sv.["id"], name = sv.["name"]) // here works perfectly the data is set
     getInfo()

   }

  fun getInfo() {
        //debuging here user data is ok
       viewmodelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

           repository.getInfo(id = user.id) // here's the problem  user.id is empty 
         }

    }

 }

Before executing the getInfo method user data is ok and after the coroutine finishes too
I have tested without Dispatchers.IO and  it works but I need to run it in IO thread and  I would like to know why this error happens and find any solution to that
If i do the following it works fine:
  fun getInfo() {
    val id=user.id
   viewmodelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

       repository.getInfo(id = id) 
     }



}

however I'd like to know why it doesn't work the other way :

According to Android's documentation, you should be using a SavedStateViewModelFactory to create a SaveStateHandle that is passed to your ViewModel constructor.
The error indicates that you are creating the SaveStateHandle directly within your composable instead of using a factory.
Try the methodology described in this other post.

i  can retrieve the information well , i have no problems with the savestatehandle,the problem is inside the IO coroutine

The problem you are having is due to how MutableState is used and when the user mutation is initialized in your ViewModel. The main problem is that getInfo() is called before the user state is fully updated. Even if the user is added to the init block, the actual value may not be immediately available in the coroutine of getInfo(), which is the empty user.id
Make sure the user is installed before calling getInfo(): You can delay calling getInfo() until after the user has fully initialized. Use the LaunchedEffect method to trigger getInfo() only when the user is launched.
 class MyViewModel(
    repository: Repository,
    sv: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {

    var user by mutableStateOf(User(id = "", name = ""))
        private set

    init {
        // Initialize the user with SavedStateHandle data
        sv.get<String>("id")?.let { id ->
            sv.get<String>("name")?.let { name ->
                user = User(id = id, name = name)

                // Ensure getInfo is only called after user is updated
                getInfo()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun getInfo() {
        // Check if user id is set correctly
        if (user.id.isNotEmpty()) {
            viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                // Now the user.id should be available here
                repository.getInfo(id = user.id)
            }
        } else {
            // Handle empty user case if needed
        }
    }
}

PS: In viewmodel class you should avoid using android related code.
Instead of using mutableStateOf(Its part of androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf) use Flow, StateFlow, Channel, LiveData as per requirement.

sorry , but  user state is fully updated before launching the coroutine, i checked that by debbuging

Just give a try with the above code, if it have same problem please let me know.

This happens because of two different threads. What happening here is that your code below is running on Main Thread by default.
 init {

 user = User(id = sv.["id"], name = sv.["name"]) // here works perfectly the data is set
 getInfo()

}

While getInfo() launch its New Thread.
Even though by looking you can say user object is created before getInfo(). So, getInfo() should have user and execute after user initialization is complete. But it is not a case, as you are creating New Thread in getInfo().  System will not wait for user complete initialization as code is asynchronized. It will run  getInfo() on different thread.
Solution is to move both code in a same thread or add little delay between two calls which give some time for initialization of user
Best Practices

MutableState object should not use in ViewModel. Replace MutableState with LiveData or flow and convert LiveData or flow to State object when access in UI

init{ } should not be use to perfrom action. It should use for initialization. getInfo() should be call from UI and not directly from init{ }



thanks for your response now  i can see the problem is related to ComposeState and thread switch , but i dont agree with : MutableState object should not use in ViewModel(even in the official docs you can find them)
init{ } should not be use to perfrom action. It should use for initialization. getInfo() should be call from UI and not directly from init{ }:  the reason i call it there is that I want to call it once , if i do it from UI , it will be triggered every recreation (configuration changes)

Instead of MutableState you should use MutableStateFlow in your view models, because it is thread-safe (MutableStateFlow.value documentation):

This property is thread-safe and can be safely updated from concurrent coroutines without external synchronization.

MutableState is a Compose feature and uses Compose Snapshot system. Changes made to mutable state values won't be seen by other threads until current snapshot is applied.  There is a tracker issue with a similar problem and here is a quote from explanation from comment #7:

I believe this is because viewModelScope uses Dispatchers.Main.immediate, which means the coroutine starts undispatched and so your first state access happens in the same snapshot as the initialization.


Also, you shouldn't switch dispatchers in ViewModel, repository.getInfo should be main-safe.

thanks for your suggestion , even though   I find compose state more practical and easier than StateFlow for data holding now I see it has this serious disadvantage
